# Why has my CPU suddenly started running hot?

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I have an i7 920, zalman cnps9900 heatsink and fan, arctic silver thermal paste and gigabyte mb with no overclocking at the moment. I have three internal fans one push and 2 pull. but my cpu has recently started to run hotter. I have sounds enabled in bios above 70C. Checked using core temp and speedfan it looks even worse. These are at idle! Core temp says i am running around 52c and speedfan a touch higher. Vcore1 1.23v, vcore2 1.41V, 2670 mhz, vbat 3.26V full fan power (Can't post images without 10 rep).

I have cleaned it thoroughly including the heat sink where I did alcohol wipe off existing paste and reapplied a thermal as per guidelines but still no joy.

Anyone got any ideas. Could it be my cpu/mb is slowly dying?

PS I do have reasonable ventilation and tend to leave the computers I have on or in sleep.

Comment: Why are you worried about those temperatures.  They are well below the thermal limits of the CPU.  Which basically means there is zero performance impact.

Comment: Really I thought with that cooler i should in the sub 40 range?

Comment: What levels can I let it get upto without impact? mainly asking cos with the Witcher 3 it is staying above 70C  for a prolonged period.

Comment: The Witcher 3 is a graphic intensive program that is likely pushing your hardware to its limits.  Unless your computer is overheating, and shutting down, or the CPU frequency is being downclocked because of the temperatures there will be zero performance impact.

Comment: Sub 40 is nice, if you can manage it, but not explicitly required.  My i7-860 regularly gets up to 70+ degrees (stock cooler) when gaming and has been fine for 4 years.  Check for dust clogging the fins of your cooler, and make sure that the fan moves freely.

Comment: Make a right click on taskbar and run taskmanager from menu. What is CPU loading shown there ? If it constantly high value (bigger than 20%) than spot which process are doing this. Usually it is a viruses or  ant-viruses(last one thinks that they only one software on computer and doing whatever they want :) )

Comment: By the way, DO NOT apply too thick layer of thermopaste. It should be a VERY THIN layer. It just should fill micro spots to extend area of contact with CPU. Even the best pastes cant replace real metal-heartsick and worst part - it dry out over time and became thermo-isolator instead of conductor

Answer (score -2):

Everyone attacks the hardware.  I think it is an intrustion, or out-of-sync software.  When sudden and furious overheating happens to me I go into the Task Manager (Ctl-Alt-Del), hit the processes tab, order the CPU column to see which program is burning up the greatest CPU percentage, and if it isn't a critical system or program I 'end process'.  It is something that doesn't belong there or is corrupted.  You should see a difference more-or-less immediately as the computer is relieved of some unnecessary and labor-intensive program consuming all the power.

Comment: There is absolutely no evidence that the authors hardware was being attacked by a malicious party.

Comment: You must be a seller of those heat pastes, fans and other expensive cures.  Not an answer for everything, but it costs nothing to check your own Task Manager and see whether what I said is so or no.

Comment: Thermal paste and heat sink fans serve a specific purpose. 
I am not a manufacture of any computer related merchandise.